# Why in PhpStorm no dirs/files can be added to my scope?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

What happened with my PhpStorm 2019.2.3 that opening new PHP/Laravel project
and trying to add new scope in search dialog my project is empty and no dirs/files can be added to my scope?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the "funnel" icon: when enabled it will show only included files/folders. For brand new/empty scope it will naturally show nothing.

[image]